# Single Page theme

Tags: theme-development, themes, templates, page-template

I would like to build a wordpress website which is inspired by the home page of the Ace Hotel http://www.acehotel.com/neworleans. I need the content to be easily updatable by the users (non developers). 
Can I use a template\theme or is this to customised and non standard?

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of one page themes for Wordpress _ here's a recent link to some of them >>> https://colorlib.com/wp/best-one-page-wordpress-themes/ 
 _ and another one with one page themes that are free >>>
https://www.codeinwp.com/blog/free-one-page-wordpress-themes/

i suspect you might be looking for more detail about 'customizable' but you would need to clarify your question by giving a little more detail

Comment: since I don't have my design yet, the best reference I have is this ace hotel page with all the different components on it e.g. Booking calendar, images etc. and of course my concern is that all the content would be easily editable and I won't need a developer for every change

Comment: yes Oded _ i looked at the Ace Hotel page _ it is part of a much bigger network of pages for many hotels _ actually with the booking calendar etc it's no longer a one page website _ but am i mistaken? are you looking for someone to build this site?

Comment: My site will also have one long home page and maybe 2 or 3 smaller pages which spin off the home page. I don't have all the designs yet but I will definitely need someone to consult if the design can be developed and of course someone to develop it.

Comment: ok Oded _ when you're ready i'd be happy to help : ) check out my profile ; )